# Highlight row when two cells match

Tags: row, highlight

I have a sheet where on column "F" I enter the number of items purchased and on column "I" the number of items sold.The actual data starts at row 4. I want to change the color of the rows when the number of sold items matches the number of purchased items. I was able to do that with conditional formatting and the formula : =$F4=$I4 . This works ok but my problem now is that all the empty rows change color since there is no data in either of the columns and so they match. I tried filling out the sold items column with 0 but it didn't work. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it works :
=AND($F4>0,($I4+$J4+$K4)=$F4)
This way the row will get highlighted when the sum of I+J+K = F but only if there is a value bigger than 0 in F.